# Об отчествах

Tags: словообразование, ономастика

Раньше говорили не Иван Иванович, а Иван, Иванов сын. Но "Иванов" - это, скорее, фамилия. Что же за "-ич" или "-овна" такие? Что они означают и откуда взялись?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Форма мужского отчества в современном русском языке с окончанием на **-ович** (после основ на мягкую согласную **-евич**) восходит к отчествам древнерусских князей и знати Московской Руси; подлые (незнатные) люди не имели права пользоваться такими отчествами. Русские отчества начали употребляться весьма рано; первое упоминание об этом относится к 945 году. Однако до XIII века частота употребления отчеств была невысокой.

Начиная с XVI века, именование с **-ович** считалось особой привилегией, такое право незнатным людям даровалось лично царём и за особые заслуги. Так, в 1610 году царь Василий Шуйский, в благодарность за содействие купцов Строгановых в присоединении Урала и Сибири к Московскому государству, повелел Максиму и Никите Строгановым, их потомкам и потомкам Семёна (Иоанникиевича) Строганова писаться с **-вичем** и даровал особое звание именитых людей. В XVII столетии Строгановы были единственной купеческой фамилией, носившей это звание.

Отчества незнатных людей в России первоначально образовывались как краткая форма притяжательного прилагательного от соответствующего имени, например: *Иван Петров сын* или, в более позднем варианте, *Иван Петров*; *Фёдор Лукин сын — Фёдор Лукин*. В определённый момент отчество могло стать наследственной фамилией, таким образом сын Ивана Петрова звался *Василий Иванов сын Петров*, его внук — *Николай Васильев сын Петров* и т.д.

В современном русском языке **женское отчество** образуется двумя способами, причём оба они по форме восходят к отчествам простолюдинов:
-- Отчества, образованные от мужских имён, заканчивающихся на согласный, образуются путём перевода имени-основы в краткую форму притяжательного прилагательного с добавлением к нему окончания **-на**: Борис — Борисов — Борисовна, Андрей — Андреев — Андреевна.
-- Отчества, образованные от мужских имён, заканчивающихся на гласный, образуются путём перевода имени-основы в краткую форму притяжательного прилагательного с добавлением к нему окончания **-ична**: Лука — Лукин — Лукинична, Фома — Фомин — Фоминична. Как это часто бывает в русском языке, это правило имеет исключения: например, Зосима — Зосимин, но Зосимовна, Никита — Никитин, но Никитична, Савва — Саввин, но Саввична. Критерием здесь является удобопроизносимость, благозвучность отчества: *Зосиминична* или *Саввинична* явно режут слух.

Большинство современных русских фамилий имеет патронимическое происхождение, то есть происходит от отчеств. Как в русском, так и в других славянских языках из-за морфологических особенностей языка женские фамилии, как правило, отличаются по форме от мужских.

Comment: А как тогда быть с Ермаком? Известно, что он был сын извозчика, а вовсе не дворянин, но, тем не менее, он был Василий Тимофеевич.

Comment: С Ермаком, действительно, ясности нет. Вопросы и о его происхождении, и об имени до сих пор обсуждаются. Известно, что Ермак был на службе у Строгановых, но еще до того, как это семейство получило от царя привилегию писать отчества с -вич. Сомнительно, что Ермака при жизни называли Тимофеевичем. Но это вопрос к историкам.

Comment: Версия об имени "Василий Тимофеевич" сомнительна. Она базируется на нехристианском проискождении имени Ермак, но скорее всего речь идёт о народном варианте имени Ермолай (по третьей версии - Герман, но она ещё боеее натянута).  
Касательно же отчества есть очень простое объяснение. Величиали Тимофеевичем Ермака нефофициально, не имея на то высочайшего разречения, такое случалось, на роток не накинешь платок. Ну иногда это попадало и в бумаги. Сам же он вроде подписывлся Ермак Тимофеев. Впрчем, даже вопрос о его грамотности остаётся открытым.

Comment: @olsa Ну, совсем не освещена тема мужских отчеств от Савва, Лука, Никита, Мина, Сила, Анна, Надежда(наверное, еще есть, или были, подобные).




0.